# Replace fixed image at scroll down and change it to relative after

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to do is a onepage website where the first "section" is a big background image (actually 4 of them, same size and same position) which should change when the user scrolls ( Just accessed the website - image1 ; Scrolled down once - image2; Scrolled down once again: image3 and so on). I tried with the js from http://jsfiddle.net/WTkqn/, but the problem is the images are fixed, though I need the webpage to scroll down as usually after the last image. I'm pretty new to javascript so any help would be highly appreciated.

As an example is http://airnauts.com/, after all the scrolling to the top area is done, the website scrolls down to the rest of the content.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var offset2 = $(document).height();
   var lineHF = offset2 - $("#bottommark").position().top;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var offset1 = $(document).height();
        var offset = $(window).scrollTop();
        var lineH = offset1 - $("#bottommark").position().top - offset;
        var lineHpart = lineHF/5;

        $("span").html(lineH);
            if (lineH > lineHpart*4) {
                $("#animation").attr("src", "http://coverjunction.s3.amazonaws.com/manual/low/colorful1.jpg");
            }
            if ((lineH < lineHpart*4) && (lineH > lineHpart*3)) {
                $("#animation").attr("src", "http://coverjunction.s3.amazonaws.com/manual/low/colorful2.jpg");
            }
            if ((lineH < lineHpart*3) && (lineH > lineHpart*2)) {
                $("#animation").attr("src", "http://coverjunction.s3.amazonaws.com/manual/low/colorful3.jpg");
            }
            if (lineH < lineHpart*2 && lineH > lineHpart*1) {
                $("#animation").attr("src", "http://coverjunction.s3.amazonaws.com/manual/low/colorful4.jpg");
            }
            if (lineH < lineHpart) {
                $("#animation").attr("src", "http://coverjunction.s3.amazonaws.com/manual/low/colorful5.jpg");
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I've added an additional condition `lineH > lineHpart/2` in the last `if-else` statement which coincides with the height of the image. Also, in the last `else`, i've changed the css property from `position:fixed` to `position:relative`. On the way up, once the condition matches for last `if-else`, it would set the property from `position:relative` to `position:fixed`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var offset2 = $(document).height();
   var lineHF = offset2 - $("#bottommark").position().top; 
    var changeRelative = false;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var offset1 = $(document).height();
        var offset = $(window).scrollTop();
        var lineH = offset1 - $("#bottommark").position().top - offset;
        var lineHpart = lineHF/5;
         $("#animation").css("position","fixed"); // set position:fixed by default
        $("span").html(lineH);
            if (lineH > lineHpart*4) {
                $("#animation").attr("src", "http://coverjunction.s3.amazonaws.com/manual/low/colorful1.jpg");
            }
            else if ((lineH < lineHpart*4) && (lineH > lineHpart*3)) {
                $("#animation").attr("src", "http://coverjunction.s3.amazonaws.com/manual/low/colorful2.jpg");
            }
            else if ((lineH < lineHpart*3) && (lineH > lineHpart*2)) {
                $("#animation").attr("src", "http://coverjunction.s3.amazonaws.com/manual/low/colorful3.jpg");
            }
            else if (lineH < lineHpart*2 && lineH > lineHpart*1) {
                $("#animation").attr("src", "http://coverjunction.s3.amazonaws.com/manual/low/colorful4.jpg");             
            }
            else if (lineH < lineHpart && lineH > lineHpart/2) {

                $("#animation").attr("src", "http://coverjunction.s3.amazonaws.com/manual/low/colorful5.jpg");                
            }
            else 
            {
                 $("#animation").css("position","relative");
            }
        });        
    });
```

Here's a working example : https://jsfiddle.net/WTkqn/301/

Comment: Thanks, but it's not quite doing the job, at the begging there is no content below the image, but after full scroll down the top images aren't fixed :(
Here: https://jsfiddle.net/denea/WTkqn/299/